# What is (button) in android?

Tags: android, button

(I am new to android programming) I've seen this piece of code which assigns a predefined button to variable b:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

It's all clear for me (to me?), but I just don't get one thing: what is that `(Button)`?!

Comment: We call that *casting* in the magical world of programming

Comment: `Button` is a `Button` not sure how else to say it

Comment: read about casting https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: It literally means "convert to type Button".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Button) is a typecast. Every widget that comes back from findViewById is a View. To treat it as a button, you must explicitly tell the compiler that it is a Button.

More information on findViewById here, in the Android documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Just to further explain to the poster:

When you create a button in your layout, you know it's a button, but your program doesn't know it's a button. By casting it to a Button you're basically telling the compiler "I promise this will be a Button". Your program will probably crash if you're lying about it being a Button.

Answer (score 1):

when you are calling `findViewByID(...)` it returns a View type. Button is a child class of View and by saying `(Button)` you are type casting it which will allow you to use the methods/functions in the Button class.